# Html tabIndex with the multiple values not getting focused

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use to `tabIndex`, Here

```
A simple HTML file

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 tabIndex="0">With 0 </h1>
<h1 tabIndex="0">With second 0 </h1>

<h1 tabIndex="1">With 1 </h1>

<h1 tabIndex="2">With 2 </h1>
<h1 tabIndex="1">With 1 </h1>

<h1 tabIndex="3">With 3 </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

So, was expecting on click of `Tab` from `keyboard` first focus should be on

```
with 0 -> With second 0 -> With 1 -> With 2 -> With 1 -> With 3
```

But Not getting the expected result.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve exactly?  Are you trying to establish a custom tab order? Messing with the tab order is pretty bad practise, in terms of accessibility and UX.

Comment: Actually, I have a table where when I use tab then its focus getting changed horizontally, trying to make it vertically

Comment: Can you post your code?  Whenever you're tabbing your browser follows logical tab order (so from top to bottom), this includes links, buttons and such will be tabbed to - if you have a table with a row of links, it will tab horizontally if the scope of the table is set to row.

Comment: It is not links but it has some input boxes

Comment: So it's behaving like it should. What you're saying is you want to tab to the first one in every column, then the second one in every column?

Comment: first in every row